# How to re-structure the file using AWK?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have written a code to re-structure the csv file based on the control file, The control file looks like below.

```
Control file : 

1,column1
3,column3
6,column6
4,column4
-1,column9
```

Based on the above control file i have taken the index's 1,3,6,4,-1 columns in source.csv file and created new file by using paste command.incase if index value is -1 in control file i have to insert the entire column as null and header name will be column9.

**Code :**

```
var=1
while read line
do
    t=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d, -f1)
    if [ $t != -1 ]
    then
        cut -d, -f$t source.csv >file_$var.csv
    else
        touch file_$var.csv
    fi
    var=$((var+1))
done < "$file"
ls -v file_*.csv | xargs paste -d, > new_file.csv
```

Is there a way to convert these lines into AWK , Suggest me some ideas.

Before Running script:

**sample.csv**

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Output:

**new_file.csv**

```
column1,column3,column6,column4,column9
a,c,f,d,
```

column9 is -1 indicate null or just , separated indicate null.

Basic intention is to restructure the source file based on the control file.

**Script:**

```
#Greenplum Database details to read target file structure from Meta Data Tables.

export PGUSER=xxx
export PGPORT=5432
export PGHOST=10.100.20.10
export PGDATABASE=fff

SCHEMA='jiodba'

##Function to explain usage of this script
usage() {
echo "Usage: program.sh -s <Source_folder> -t <Target_folder> -f <file_name> ";
exit 1; }

source_folder=$1
target_folder=$2
file_name=$3


#removes the existing file from current directory

rm -f file_struct_*.csv

# Reading the Header from the Source file.

v_source_header=`head -1 $file_name`

IFS=","     # Set the field separator
set $v_source_header      # Breaks the string into $1, $2, ...
i=1
for item    # A for loop by default loop through $1, $2, ...
do
    echo "$i,$item">>source_header.txt
    ((i++))
done

sed -e "s/
//" source_header.txt | sed -e "s/ \{1,\}$//" > source_headers.txt

rm -f source_header.txt

#Get the Target header information from Greenplum Meta data Table and writing into target_header.txt file.

psql -t -A -F "," -c "select Target_column_position,Target_column_name from jiodba.etl_tbl_sequencing where source_file_name='$file_name' order by target_column_position" > target_header.txt

#Removing the trail space and control characters.

sed -e "s/
//" target_header.txt | sed -e "s/ \{1,\}$//" > target_headers.txt

rm -f target_header.txt

#Compare the Source Header Target Structure and generate the Difference.

awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} {if ($2 in a) print a[$2]","$2; else print "-1," $2}' source_headers.txt  target_headers.txt >>tgt_struct_output.txt

#Loop to Read column index from the tgt_struct_output.txt and cut it in Source file.


file='tgt_struct_output.txt'
var=1
while read line
do
t=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d, -f1)
if [ $t != -1 ]
then
cut -d, -f$t $file_name>file_struct_$var.csv
else
touch file_struct_$var.csv
fi
var=$((var+1))
done<"$file"


awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR {c[++n]=$2; a[$2]=$1;next} FNR==1{f=""; for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
  {printf "%s%s", f, c[i]; b[++k]=i; f=OFS} print "";next}
  {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if(a[c[i]]>0) printf "%s%s", $a[c[i]], OFS; print""
   }' tgt_struct_output.txt $file_name


#Paste the different file(columns)into single file

ls -v file_struct_*.csv | xargs paste -d,| sed -e "s/
//" > new_file.csv

new_header=`cut -d "," -f 2 target_headers.txt | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'`

#Replace the header with original target header incase if column doesnt exit in the target table structure.

sed "1s/.*/$new_header/" new_file.csv

#Removing the Temp files.

rm -f file_struct_*.csv
rm -f source_headers.txt target_headers.txt tgt_struct_output.txt
touch file_struct_1.csv #Just to avoid the error in shell
```

**Sample.csv**

```
BP ID,Prepaid Account No,CurrentMonetary balance ,charge Plan names ,Provider contract id,Contract Item ID,Start Date,End Date
1100001538,001000002506,251,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN ,00000000000000000141,[B2] R2 LTE CHARGE PLAN _00155D10E20D1ED39A8E146EA7169A2E00155D10E20D1ED398FD63624498DB4A,16-Oct-12,18-Oct-12
1100003404,001000004029,45.22,B0.3 ECS_CHARGE_PLAN DROP1 V3,00000000000000009349,B0.3 ECS  DROP2 V0.2_00155D10E20D1ED39A8E146EA7169A2E00155D10E20D1ED398FD63624498DA2E,16-Nov-13,23-Nov-13
1100006545,001000006620,388.796,B0.3 ECS_CHARGE_PLAN DROP1 V3,00000000000000010477,B0.3 ECS  DROP2 V0.2_00155D10E20D1ED39A8E146EA7169A2E00155S00E20D1ED398FD63624498DA2E,07-Nov-12,07-Nov-13
```

Comment: Can you post the format of the desired output?

Comment: @Paul Please find the revised question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR {c[++n]=$2; a[$2]=$1;next} FNR==1{f=""; for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
  {printf "%s%s", f, c[i]; b[++k]=i; f=OFS} print "";next}
  {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if(a[c[i]]>0) printf "%s%s", $a[c[i]], OFS; print""
   }' ctrl.csv sample.csv
column1,column3,column6,column4,column9
a,c,f,d,
```

Comment: The way it works is perfectly fine , but i required the actual column values from the sample.csv file based on the ctrl file, instead its printing the same index fom ctrl.csv file.

Comment: Partially working , please find the script uses paste command. same while loop need to be modified to awk.

Comment: I didn't get. Isn't this awk script producing exact same output you expected?

Comment: Yes its partially working.. So i have attached my script which will do the same thing using paste command.

Comment: Still not getting. You asked for an awk script and that is what my answer does. Now if this awk is somehow not working then you need to tell clearly for which input it is not working and what is your expected output.